# jBoss EAP - full-ha profile required for stateless servers?

Tags: jboss, load-balancing

jBoss EAP 6.2 supports full and full-ha profiles (amongst others). In standalone deploy, we use domain mode with full profile for an app.

App that we have is primarily having/exposing RESTful services which are stateless - there is a administration web portal, but it is ok to not have session replication for this (i.e. if one server goes down, it is acceptable for users to lose the browsing session and login again). app does not make use of EJBs.

In deployment, if we have a hardware loadbalancer that is able to route requests to nodes in active-active mode, then, is it ok to just go with full profile on nodes and not use the full-ha profile ? or is there a benefit to be got from using the full-ha profile? using the former approach simplifies deployment and makes spinning up a new VM with the app relatively easier.

Any inputs/directions/pointers in this regard would be most useful.

Answer (score 0):

The used JBoss profile depends on what you need from it. `standalone-full-ha` provides Infinispan, Web-Session and HornetQ (JMS) replication whereas `standalone-ha` provides no JMS.

You can run active-active clusters with load balancers in front with the `standalone` profile as long as you do not replicate data/states using JGroups, Infinispan and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the input here - did end up using full-ha for JMS in cluster mode even with the LBs being used.